# What does forKey mean? What does it do?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm guessing that it gives the object that is being added to the NSMutableDictionary or NSDictionary a name to access it. But, I have to confirm it. Can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 6):

Dictionaries are data structures that contain key-value pairs. They're also known as hash tables. So yes, you use a key to refer to its corresponding value.

For the following dictionary:

```
// Pseudo-code, not actual Objective-C code, merely for illustration
// (This {} syntax would be really nice to have though...)
NSDictionary *dict = {
    @"one" => NSNumber (1),
    @"two" => NSNumber (2)
};
```

The following code yields `1`:

```
NSNumber *one = [dict objectForKey:@"one"];
NSLog(@"%d", [one intValue]);
```

Comment: oh... thanks... So if you give the object a key to access it's value or to change it. Am I correct?